# Can change in kinetic energy be negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

Can change in kinetic energy be negative? If yes then kinetic energy would be negative which is not possible please explain

Comment: I really don't understand why you asked the same question twice? Maybe the question was closed first at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Promoted from a comment by [Andrei Geanta](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/170640/andrei-geanta):

> If the speed of the object is decreasing, then the change in kinetic energy is negative. Kinetic energy cannot be negative, but the change in kinetic energy can be.